# struggling to understand Equals()

Tags: c#, .net, equals

So as I understand it Equals() determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.

So if i have this Player class:

```
public class Player
{
    int score;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone(); 
    }

    public void SetScore(int i)
    {
        this.score = i; 
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        return this.score; 
    }
}
```

Ant then I instantiate two Player's like this:

```
Player p1 = new Player();
p1.SetScore(7);
Player p2 = (Player)p1.Clone();
```

Why is it that does Equals() return false when used like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(p1.Equals(p2)); // prints "False" to console
```

How are they not equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because unless you override the Equals function, it is comparing the references to see if they are the *same* object.

See [Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

There are cases where you may get some reference, and want to see if it is a certain object. Say:

```
Player myFavorite = new Player();
//do stuff...
Player fastest = GetFastestPlayer();
if (myFavorite == fastest)
    // I'm happy
```

Comment: what good is comparing the references to see if they are the same object?

Comment: @EpicNobody: It's really the only sensible way to implement `.Equals()` on `System.Object`, since that class otherwise knows nothing of classes which inherit from it.

Answer (score 4):

Jonathon Rienhart is correct - unless you override `Equals` then you're only checking *instances*, not values. It doesn't matter if the two objects are identical, if they aren't the same object then they are not equal. See also: I am the same person as myself, but I'm not the same person as my identical twin.

If you override the `Equals` operator you can define what constitutes equality - for example, you might want two `Players` to be consider equal if they have the same score.

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
{
    var player = (Player)obj;

    if (player != null && player.score== this.score)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Normally, however, you wouldn't want these two players to be equal. Surely it's possible to have two players with the same score?

Comment: When implementing `Equals`, I would do `var player = obj as Player;` to avoid an `InvalidCastException`.